# How to Prefix Classes on my iOS Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have a custom framework and this framework uses a third party library. I want to distribute the current version of the third party library, but some developers report the duplicate symbols errors. How can I prefix the classes? I rename all the files but I still have the duplicate problem

PS: Cocoapods is not a option

Comment: Are you sure the duplicate symbol issues are due to two people who happen to name a class the same? Provide details about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no name-spacing in Objective-C. So you have to prefix the class with a short acronym. Say if you worked for the ACME Corporation, you could have `ACMEProduct` or `ACMEUser`.

Comment: @Charlkers yeah I tried to change the classes name but even using another name, we still have the problem

Comment: @DavidCortes that should probably be a separate question, that includes a build log showing the duplicate symbols.